# Identify the regions in $(\alpha_{1},\ \alpha_{2})$ plane for which $f_{\alpha_{1},\ \alpha_{2}}$ is a convex or concave function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

A family of functions. For constants $\alpha_{1}$ $\alpha_{2}$,

let $f_{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}}:R^{2}_{+} \rightarrow R_{+}$ be defined as:

$\hspace{4 cm}$ $f_{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}}(x_{1},\ x_{2})= x_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}x_{2}^{\alpha_{2}}, \hspace{2 cm} x_{i} \geq 0$

Identify and draw the regions in the $(\alpha_{1},\ \alpha_{2})$ plane for which $f_{\alpha_{1},\ \alpha_{2}}$ is a

(a) convex function

(b) concave function

**Advance phase**:
Generalize the previous result to this case:

for a vector $\alpha \in R^{n},$
let $f_{\alpha}:R^{n}_{+} \rightarrow R_{+}$ be defined as:

$\hspace{4 cm}$ $f_{\alpha}(x)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1} ^{n} x_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}, \hspace{2 cm} x_{i} \geq 0$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There is first  and  second  order  characterizations  of  convex functions [here](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Eaaa/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec7_gh.pdf)

Well known result is following:
Suppose function $f$ is defined and have continuous second partial derivatives in interior of convex set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. $f$ is convex if and only if when quadratic form
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}f_{ij}(x)\xi_i \xi_j$$
is  positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks very much for your hint,Can you Please explain more the part which are more related to the question?

Comment: @Nilo. Search, please, in brought link exactly "first and second order characterizations"(Theorem 2). Also, added to answer one more theorem.